# Mysterious milliseconds number found in Java Date/Calendar object

Tags: java, date, calendar

Got a strange weirdness when using `Date`s and `Calendar`. Point is I want to create a specific date e.g.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Now the thing is: it shows the correct date, but when debugging I see under the date-variable a "fasttime" of e.g. `-3599459`. This makes my `JUnit` tests fail, because the expected value is `-3600000`. 
It seems the Calendar adds 541 milliseconds or something like when initializing...

Question is: is it not possible to simply create a fixed date without this 'i'm adding some milliseconds in the background'-ghost function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line before calling `cal.getTime()`:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

This will make sure you set the milliseconds to zero.

Answer (score 12):

From the docs for the [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method you're calling:

> Sets the values for the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. Previous values of other fields are retained. If this is not desired, call clear() first.

So it's retaining the millisecond value. It's not *adding* some milliseconds - it's taking the system time when you call `getInstance`, as it's documented to do.

Call [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28%29) first, or explicitly set the millisecond value. (Personally I'd use `clear()`. I'd also explicitly set the time zone, just to make it clearer which time you're expecting.

Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to start with - it's a *much* more pleasant date/time API.

Comment: @Malvin: Note that if you use `clear()`, that will be correct for the cases where you only set the year/month/day, or year/month/day/hour/minute... this is why I prefer using `clear()` over the answer you've accepted of *just* setting the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used best practice is to introduce a `Clock` object to wrap all access to your Date/Time API.

Essentially, you have two implementations - a `SystemTimeClock` which forwards everything to your chosen Date/Time provider, and a mocked implementation to use for tests.

That way, your code becomes independent of specifics of the API and your tests run smoothly.

Comment: Joda Time has a similar feature for setting the system time virtually to a specific moment, which is useful for testing; see the methods in class `org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils`.

Comment: Indeed. Turns out there was a similar question where Jon Skeet gave a similar answer to mine with a similar comment to yours...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622194/time-dependent-unit-tests

Answer (score 0):

When working with dates, I'm pretty happy with the library Joda Time. I know it's not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe, it's worth looking into: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/
JavaDocs: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: I would use JodaTime, but unfortunately I am not allowed to use any further libraries.

Comment: The new java.time package, built into Java 8 and inspired by Joda-Time, is another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "set" does not set the "millisecond" value, so the millisecond value is still the value it had when you created the calendar with getInstance. You can call

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

before calling getTime, this will make sure that the milliseconds are 0. You can also directly create a gregorian calendar:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
assertEquals(0, cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

If you want a more complete implementation of calendar and time functionality you can use Joda Time instead of the standard Java Calendar API.

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(new Date());
```