# Use AOP to mock System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop

I need to replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with my own realization within all third-party jars in application. Can I use load-time weaving or other way to do it?

**Note**: I can't replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with my own interface and use DI to achieve it. I need to replace such calls in all jars(e.g.: Spring ones): `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `new Date`, `new DateTime()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() replace method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239859/java-lang-system-currenttimemillis-replace-method)

Comment: i need it in load time, not compile time as in that answer