# How to test the time-dependent business logic in spring data and spring data rest projects?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

What are the best practices to test the time-dependent business logic in Spring Data and Spring Data REST projects? 
How to set different "system" time in one test method?

For example - we have two different algorithms to solve the same task - one algorithm is used until 11-00, another one - after 11-00.

Or we have a task that must be performed only on Mondays...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time dependent unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622194/time-dependent-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

If a method depends on the current date or time, add the current time as a parameter:

```
public void doSomething(LocalDateTime now) {
    // does something time-dependent
}
```

The real code invokes this method with `doSomething(LocalDateTime.now())`.
The tests invoke this method with "test dates"

```
doSomething(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 3, 5, 13, 37)); // Sunday
doSomething(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 3, 6, 13, 37)); // Monday
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not suitable for this situation.
(Do you have an experience in Spring Data or SDR?)

Comment: I used some basic functions several times. Do you have an example?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/